# Is it possible for me to squeeze out any extra efficiency using PLINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, parallel-processing

I'm trying to solve a problem that is to find all the prime numbers in a given range whose every digit is also prime.

e.g. in the range `[1, 100]` the answer is `8` because `2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 37, 53, 37` are all the numbers satisfying it.

My current solution is correct

```
// Yields all the numbers in the range [start, end] that could be primes,
// by taking into account the fact that a prime is either 2, 3, 6k + 1 or 6k - 1
static IEnumerable<long> PossiblePrimeNumbers(long start, long end)
{
    if(start <= 2 && end >= 2)
        yield return 2;
    if(start <= 3 && end >= 3)
        yield return 3;
    for(long n = (start / 6 + 1) * 6; ; n += 6)
    {
        if((n - 1) <= end)
            yield return (n - 1);
        if((n + 1) <= end)
            yield return (n + 1);
        else break;
    }
}

// Map for fast checking of whether a digit 0, 1, ..., 9 is a prime
static bool[] IsPrimeDigit = { false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false };

// True or false depending on whether m is prime
static bool IsPrime(long m)
{
    long boundary = (long)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(m));

    bool isPrime = true;

    for(long i = 2; i <= boundary; ++i)
    {
        if(m % i == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isPrime;
}

// True or false depending on whether all the digits of m are prime and
// whether m itself is prime
static bool IsMegaprime(long m)
{
    return m.ToString().All(c => IsPrimeDigit[c - '0']) && IsPrime(m);
}

// Counts the number of "megaprimes" (defined above) in the range [first, last]
static int NumberMegaprimes(long first, long last)
{
    return PossiblePrimeNumbers(first, last).AsParallel().Count(m => IsMegaprime(m));
}

static void Main(String[] args)
{
    long first = 1;
    long last = 100;
    Console.WriteLine(NumberMegaprimes(first, last)); // should print 8
}
```

and you can even see that I've added an `.AsParallel()` to try and speed it up.

Are there any obvious ways to speed this up? (Other than getting rid of LINQ)

Comment: This is more of a job for Code Review I'd say since the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

If with `AsParallel()` your CPU is hitting the 100% ceiling then - in the spirit of the question of whether you can *squeeze out extra efficiency out of PLINQ* - the short answer is No. The CPU has become your bottleneck, and your options are either to get a better CPU, or to use a better algorithm.

As Sami's comment mentioned, for help with algorithms you're better off asking in [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From parallelization standpoint there is nothing you can do more - you already moved the CPU intensive check execution in parallel.

So, are there any obvious ways to speed this up?

First, there are some obvious optimizations in both CPU bound methods. The `IsPrime` can be made to check only odd divisors:

```
static bool IsPrime(long m)
{
    if ((m & 1) == 0) return m == 2; // even
    long boundary = (long)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(m));
    for (long i = 3; i <= boundary; i += 2)
        if ((m % i) == 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

and `IsMegaprime` can use integer division for checking digits rather than `ToString` call (thus avoiding GC heap allocations):

```
static bool IsMegaprime(long m)
{
    for (long n = m; n != 0; n /= 10)
        if (!IsPrimeDigit[n % 10]) return false;
    return IsPrime(m);
}
```

Applying these trims down the execution time for range `[2, int.MaxValue]` from 32.8 sec to 12.7 sec, so it definitely is not a micro optimization.

But the main optimization would be to change the algorithm. Instead of generating possible prime numbers and checking the candidate for both all digits being primes and the number itself being prime, the algorithm can be changed to generate all possible numbers with all digits being prime and then just checking if the candidate is prime. The rationale is that this way the candidate list is greatly reduced and one of the CPU bound check is reduced.

The generation part is simple combination generator of digits { 2, 3, 5, 7 } up to range end, with multi digit combinations starting with 2 or 5 (lower digit) skipped because apparently they cannot be primes.

I have a couple posts on iterative combination generators, here is the one adjusted for this problem:

```
static readonly int[] oneDigitPrimes = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };

static readonly long[] decimalScales = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(n => (long)Math.Pow(10, n)).ToArray();

static IEnumerable<long> PossibleMegaprimeNumbers(long start, long end)
{
    var digits = oneDigitPrimes;
    var scales = decimalScales;
    var indices = new int[scales.Length];
    var results = new long[scales.Length];
    long result = 0;
    int pos = 0, index = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // Generate next numbers up to end
        do
        {
            var digit = digits[index];
            long next = result + digit * scales[pos];
            if (next >= start)
            {
                if (next > end) break;
                yield return next;
            }
            indices[pos] = index;
            results[pos] = result;
            result = next;
            index = 0;
            pos++;
            if (pos == 1 && (digit == 2 || digit == 5)) break;
        }
        while (pos < results.Length);
        // Move back and select next digit
        do
        {
            if (pos == 0) yield break;
            pos--;
            index = indices[pos];
            result = results[pos];
            index++;
        }
        while (index >= digits.Length);
    }
}
```

and the final parallelized method similar to yours:

```
static IEnumerable<long> MegaprimeNumbers(long start, long end)
{
    return PossibleMegaprimeNumbers(start, end)
        .AsParallel()
        .Where(IsPrime);
}
```

Now invoking `MegaprimeNumbers(2, int.MaxValue).Count()` took only 42 ms, which compared to initial 32.8 sec is not bad optimization I guess.