# Is there a known algorithm for getting all the numbers in a range [a, b] containing only digits from the set {d0, ..., dn}?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I was wondering whether there's an easy way to implement the method I've described in the comments below

```
// Yields all the longs in the range [first, last] that 
// are composed of the prime digits. 
// For example, if the range is [4, 50] then the numbers
// yielded are 5, 7, 22, 23, 25, 27, 32, 33, 35, 35, 
// although they don't necessarily need to be yieled in order.
static IEnumerable<long> PossiblesInRange(long first, long last)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The prime digits, in order, are

```
static long[] PrimeDigits = { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
```

Comment: no, you should know all previous primes in order to find next prime, although you can only yield primes in given range but still finding all previous primes is necessary. this may help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257/is-there-a-known-mathematical-equation-to-find-the-nth-prime

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you have a not-easy or inefficient method, or are you just asking someone to write your code?

Comment: Actually what are you asking here is part of my answer to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430807/is-it-possible-for-me-to-squeeze-out-any-extra-efficiency-using-plinq)